# Does Spring Boot Support EJB

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I have an EJB application which is running in WebSphere 7.x. We need to move away from Websphere 7.x and make this application independent of Websphere server We can use in build Tomcat or Undertow.

Does Spring Boot will support this approach?If not another option is we can use Liberty Profile of WebSphere along with Spring Boot.

We are moving towards this approach as we want to run this application in Docker.

Comment: No ... EJBs aren't supported nor is tomcat a full JEE server and as such doesn't support EJBs. You will need a full blown container like WebSphere, WebLogic, JBoss, to run EJB based applications.

Comment: @M.Deinum is it Liberty Profile will support EJB. Our main motive is package the server as part of application and run the application in Docker.

Comment: If you can stop using a full application server, and you can use Spring Boot, why do you still need to use EJB? Not using EJB is one of Spring's benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy WebSphere Liberty in a Docker container. There are official images on Docker Hub.